# Unable to install Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I downloaded Chrome deb package from official website. Whet I open using software center and click install, the button shows "installing" and reverts in a few seconds. Running 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Chrome deb package from the terminal: `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-........deb` 
After you get an error i run : `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the local file via

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/local/chrome.deb
```

If that fails - please post the output

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when you install it with the software center, does your title bar say Ubuntu software or Ubuntu software center? if it says ubuntu software, first stop what it's doing and download Ubuntu software center (same icon and everything, one works, at least in my case, maybe in yours too.) you may have to do that by running sudo apt-get software-center once you have done that make sure you have chrome downloaded then right click it and open with software CENTER. This fixed it for me, I hope it works for you. The other answers also worked for me, but I found software center to have less problems anyway.